# CascadeBeforeDelete and CascadeAfterDelete

Tags: nhibernate

Everyone:

I've just recently finished implementing a "Soft Deleting" mechanism for my database driven web product using NHibernate.  I followed the tutorial [here](http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/04/08/soft-deletes.aspx) for creating a SoftDeleteListener and it works like a charm, Kudos to the Gabriel Schenker who wrote that very good tutorial.

So, what's the problem?  Well, I updated his code for the SoftDeleteListener I've implemented, and I tested it and all seems well.  However, when I use a code template from a third party, I ALWAYS want to understand completely what every line of code is doing.  In this case, however, I've searched and searched but I cannot find any documentation on the functions of the CascadeBeforeDelete and the CascadeAfterDelete methods!  I can pretty much infer that they are doing some sort of foreign key cascading deletion functions, but the documentation on what exactly they are doing is nowhere to be found.

Can someone please point me to the proper documentation for these methods? Or, if none exists, could you kindly explain them to me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's no documentation for those methods.

What you can do is [get the NH sources](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/NHibernate/3.0.0.GA/NHibernate-3.0.0.GA-src.zip/download) and see how it's used in the code.

Comment: Thanks, Diego.  I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

After Diego's suggestion, I've taken a quick look at the NHibernate sources for these files and, from the comment blocks in the source code, have determined their functions:

CascadeBeforeDelete - Cascades the delete call to all collections of that object before the object is deleted.

CascadeAfterDelete - Cascades the delete call to all many-to-one relationships to the object  after the parent has been deleted

This was just taken from the comment directly, and I really don't have the time to thoroughly investigate these methods functions (tight deadlines keep me awake at night).  If anyone has any more information on these methods they would like to share it would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.